# Multiple Angular Material themes: getting sass map property always returns old, cached, value

Tags: angular, sass, themes, angular-material2

For multiple Angular Material themes the idea is to have a scss property which has a different value per theme. I'd like to access this sass map property from within a mixin, as is done in this article: https://sevriukovmk.medium.com/custom-angular-material-multiple-themes-dd7cb31f835

I'm accessing this sass map like this (and assigning to `background-color` just to test:

```
@use 'sass:map';

@mixin theme($theme) {
  $foreground: map.get($theme, foreground);
  $secondary-text: map.get($foreground, secondary-text);
  body {
    @debug $secondary-text;
    background-color: $secondary-text !important;
  }
}
```

Which is working, only it keeps returning an old, cached value (being `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.54)`). Funny thing is this value of `0.54` doesn't even exist anymore in the entire codebase, so this appears to be a cached value.

I ran `ng cache clean` and also disabled angular cache entirely with `ng cache disable` and `ng cache off` but the old value keeps returning.

What could be causing this?
Which other (sass) cache can i delete?

Answer (score 0):

One needs to call component dependent themes mixins, per theme.

so if this is a theme file:

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@use 'src/app/styles/abstracts/theme.functions' as functions;
@use "src/app/styles/theme-dependant.styles" as components;
@import 'src/app/styles/abstracts/theme-variables';

@include mat.core();

$grey-palette: mat.define-palette(mat.$grey-palette);
$grey-theme: functions.mat-create-theme(
  $grey-palette,
  $grey-palette,
  $warn-palette,
  $light-theme-background-palette,
  $light-theme-foreground-palette
);

@include mat.all-component-themes($grey-theme);
@include components.theme($grey-theme); // this was the important part, needs to happen per theme
```

which can look like this:

```
@use "../app.style" as app;
@use "./base/typography" as typography;

@mixin theme($theme) {
  @include app.theme($theme);
  @include typography.theme($theme);
}
```

of which the typography can look like this:

```
@use 'sass:map';
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import 'src/app/styles/abstracts/variables';
@import 'src/app/styles/layout/responsiveness';

@mixin theme($theme) {
  $foreground: map.get($theme, foreground);
  $secondary-text: map.get($foreground, secondary-text);

  $colors: map.get($theme, color);
  $primary: map.get($colors, primary);
  $accent: map.get($colors, accent);
  $primary50: mat.get-color-from-palette($primary, 50);
  $accent50: mat.get-color-from-palette($accent, 50);

  button.mat-mdc-raised-button.mat-primary {
    color: $primary50 !important;
  }
  button.mat-mdc-raised-button.mat-accent {
    color: $accent50 !important;
  }
}
```

for a full working setup of custom theme-dependant styling, per theme.
Hope it helps someone.